# How can I smooth a 2D matrix to the Nth nearest neighbours in R?

Tags: r, matrix, 2d, knn, smoothing

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
M=matrix(data = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1),ncol = 4,nrow = 4,byrow = T)
```

Which is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    1    1
```

I want to smooth this matrix to nearest neighbours (to then Nth nearest neighbours, if possible), while retaining the dimension of the original matrix, like window averaging but in 2D. To my surprise, I haven't found yet an R function that performs this calculation.

For example, if I want to smoooth it just to first neighbours, and for the sake of simplicity, using the same weights for every value averaged, the output would be:

```
M_smoothed=matrix(data = c(0,2/6,4/6,4/4,0,3/9,6/9,6/6,0,3/9,6/9,6/6,0,2/6,4/6,4/4),ncol = 4,nrow = 4,byrow = T)
```

Which is:

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0 0.3333333 0.6666667    1
[2,]    0 0.3333333 0.6666667    1
[3,]    0 0.3333333 0.6666667    1
[4,]    0 0.3333333 0.6666667    1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could try this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/oce/versions/0.1-82/topics/matrix.smooth

Comment: Thanks, @GordonShumway! That function smooths to 1st neighbours but not taking into account diagonal neighbours. It's not exactly what I'm looking for but it goes in the right direction.